# Variable binwith in geom_histogram()

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, histogram

I like to set up different binwidths in ggplot2.

As an example I use the dataset

```
library(Stat2Data)
data("YouthRisk2007")
```

```
head(YouthRisk2007)
  ride.alc.driver female grade age4 smoke DriverLicense
1               1      1    10   15     1             0
2               1      1    10   18     1             1
3               1     NA    NA   NA    NA            NA
4               0      0    11   17     0             1
5               0      0    11   17     0             1
6               0      0    11   17     1             1
```

With

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

YouthRisk2007 %>% 
    ggplot(aes(age4)) +
      geom_histogram(binwidth = 1)
```

you generate a histogram for every year.

Now I like to set up different binwidth (14-15 year, 16-17 year, 18 years [width of the classes]) so that the area is proportional to the frequency (not just the hight of the bin).
The binwidth should vary visually, not just for counting the frequency.

My first idea was to set up the binwidth as a vector `binwidth = c(2,3)` but this is not allowed.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know your desired breakpoints beforehand, you can use the `scale_x_binned()`. It requires ggplot v3.3.0+.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_bar(aes(mpg)) +
  scale_x_binned(breaks = c(10, 13, 15, 16, 25, 30))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: That looks very nice, but my R don't find the function scale_x_binned. Is there another package necessary?

Comment: No just ggplot2 version 3.3.0 (the most recent one).

Comment: Oh, I will update the package and give you feedback soon.

Comment: Do you know how are these variable bins are centered?

Comment: I presume `(upper_bound + lower_bound) / 2`. The `width()` argument of the `geom_bar()` determines how much they encroach upon the bounds. Datapoint at the exact breakpoint are counted in the right bin, unless you set `right = FALSE` in the scale.

Comment: With 
```YouthRisk2007 %>% 
        ggplot(aes(age4)) + 
            geom_bar() + 
            scale_x_binned(breaks = c(14,16,17))```
I got three bins. But I'm not sure which ages are included.

With
```YouthRisk2007 %>% 
     ggplot(aes(age4)) + 
     geom_bar() + 
     scale_x_binned(breaks = c(14,16,18))```
I just get 2 bins.
I'm a little bit confused.

Comment: You can check with `table(YouthRisk2007$age4)` what the numbers per age are. I think with `breaks = c(14,16,17)`,  if `right = TRUE`, the groups are 14-15, 16-17 and 18+. If `right = FALSE` it is 14, 15-16, 17+.

Comment: With ```scale_x_binned(breaks = c(14,16,17), right = TRUE)``` the visually binwidths are 2,1,1 and with ```scale_x_binned(breaks = c(14,16,17), right = FALSE)``` they are 2,1,1.

I cannot set it to 2,2,1.
What is wrong?

Comment: The breaks don't change, where datapoints are being counted is changing. 2, 2, 1 makes sense to me as 16-14 = 1, 17-16 = 1 and then 1 for everything that is right of 17